# How does one treat the indicator function algebraically?

Tags: indicator-function

I am supposed to find the value for which $f(\cdot)$ (I don't understand the use of the dot here either) is a PDF in the following function:
$$
f(x) = k(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x), x \in \ R
$$
I know I must make $f(\cdot)=1$ but I don't know how I am supposed to treat the indicator function algebraically. If I simply divide by it, that gives
$$
k={1\over(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x)}
$$
Is this algebraically correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "treating" it?

Comment: @Tim What operations are allowed? Is it a regular function? Is my solution for k correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I believe the notation $f(\cdot)$ just means the same thing as $f$, and the same thing as the phrase:

> The function $f$

Your solution for $k$ must be a number that does not depend on $x$, so

$$
k={1\over(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x)}
$$

does not meet those requirements.  You can certainly divide by an indicator function just like any other function, but it creates domain issues where the indicator function is zero.

Your conceptual error is this statement:

> I know I must make $f(\cdot)=1$

That's not quite right.  You need to satisfy this:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1 $$

The indicator function comes in because $f(x) = k(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x)$ is zero for all $x$ outside of the interval $(-1, 1)$, so those reigons do not contribute anything to the integral.  That is:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} k(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x) dx=  \int_{-1}^{1} k(1-x^2) dx$$

You'll have to compute this final integral, set the answer equal to one, then solve for $k$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution (is it OK to thank?) I'm trying to understand the usage of the indicator function. The codomain of f(x)=(1-x^2) is (-inf,1]. The given indicator seems to constrain this codomain to [0,1]. Is that what it is for? Why would one want that?

Comment: That is indeed what it's for.  I'm not sure without additional context what the purpose of the restriction is, it may just result in a problem that the author thought was fun or cute.